# Can't load webpages every few hours

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

**My Problem**

2 or 3 times a day, I can’t load any websites in any of my browsers. The weird part is, it’s currently only affecting my laptop and my cellphone (it used to be all internet connected devices in the house, but I may have fixed those already).

The thing is, Windows 7 still says I’m connected to the Internet. My Skype doesn't disconnect, my gaming consoles remain online, people can watch Netflix on the Roku etc… But my laptop and my cellphone can’t load websites.

It lasts for about 5 to 10 minutes before it starts loading webpages again.

**Router**

[Netgear N600](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wndr3700.aspx) Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router, model WNDR3700.

**What I’ve tried**

- I’ve re-setup my wireless settings on my router, and changed SSID.
- Changed the Ethernet cable.
- [Reset TCP/IP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357).
- Factory reset router.
- Uninstalled network card driver, and installed the latest version.
- Tried using latest router firmware updates.
- Flushed DNS with `ipconfig /flushdns`.
- Tried disabling IPv6 on my wireless connection.
- Tried using a 5Ghz signal on my cellphone; my laptop won’t detect it, but I know it used to.

**Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?**

This is pretty much driving me insane. I use my laptop for work and I browse a lot as well, so this issue is very, very annoying. I don’t exactly lose Internet access. I’m connected to my router, full strength, and I can chat on Skype, but webpages won’t load for 5-10 minutes every few hours.

Also, here’s an image of `ipconfig` result when I couldn’t load any websites:

[image]

Comment: Try disable IPv6 if activated.

Comment: @user3767013 I tried disabling IPv6 on my wireless connection, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You already tried many possibilities for a solution. Is it possible for you to try another router? I suspect a defective router. Hope this help.

Comment: @JakeGould Netgear N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router, model WNDR3700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all sounds like 802.11n network voodoo to me. The reality of 802.11n is not all devices support or behave correctly when using it.

The best advice would be to get a new router if you can. Or try to use 802.11g on you phone and laptop to see if you get a more stable connection.

The other idea is to see if your router is set to mixed mode which attempts to allow 802.11b and 802.11g connections to co-exist with 802.11n. I’m on a Mac but when I disabled mixed mode on my router and forced it to be only 802.11n things cleared up quite quickly. Of course if you disable mixed mode then any device needing 802.11b or 802.11g would not be able to connect, but if you are all on 802.11n that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I have no option to force a mode on my router, but I disabled 802.11n in my wireless settings on my laptop which I hope does the same thing your saying. I'll report back when I can, I have to wait hours to see if any fixes work since it appears at random.

Comment: I haven't encountered the error since trying this solution, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

During this Offline/Online State that you Can't access any website, On your Console (CMD) try

> ping 8.8.8.8

If you get your packets back, then try

> nslookup www.google.gr

if you don't get a result, your ISP's DNS Server is malfunctioning. 
The best thing to do is to set as Primary DNS Server 8.8.8.8 , and 8.8.4.4 , Google's DNS Servers.

If you don't get your packets either, but the other devices can connect to the Internet without problem, then you have to check your Devices for Malwares, or unconfigured Firewall, or Even a Scheduled task does this kind of thing.

In your situation even a faulty Router can cause this kind of thing. So better check up your router aswell.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had the problem since trying @JakeGould's solution, but this is useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously had this problem affecting wireless devices in my home. You have done the drivers, try updating firmware on the router itself and flushing your dns cache if it is happening on the same sites.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I've also tried router firmware updates (I've edited my question). As for dns cache, would it simply be doing ipconfig /flushdns in command line? I've also tried that, and it's all websites that won't load, not only a select few.

Comment: Do you have any external devices or interference that would disrupt your signal? Microwaves are very common especially if they are getting older, is there a shower inbetween your wireless device and access point? Water impedes the transmission of more wireless networks and microwaves output around 2.45Ghz which is very close to your access points transmission of 2.4Ghz. Unless you are already using a 5Ghz router and it is set up as such I would try that.

Comment: Yes, I might, however I never had issues before. Regardless, I enabled a 5Ghz signal on my router, and tried it on my phone (my laptop apparently won't detect it anymore, but I'm sure it did before), but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Well I think something happened you're host file.

You can check it here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

In this folder, you can find a file which name is `hosts`.

Copy to the desktop and edit with `Notepad++` or if you don't have it, just edit with Windows notepad.

If you see any web addresses that’s could be a possible reason for you’re problem.

Delete the web addresses which you can't reach and please delete the browser and also IP caching.

Maybe good if you’re pull all of you’re router and modem from the connector and plugged in again. If you have Belkin router, buy another one, because this router is a most bad all time. I know, I have had it in the past, and I have the same problem. After I changed the router everything is working out.

Comment: I did edit the hosts file before, but all my changes are commented. It's not specific websites I have trouble with, but all of them. I have a Netgear router, but it's starting to look like I may have to change it.

Comment: You have a backup from the host file?
Becouse the unvisible character also can be you're problem.

Comment: If you don't have it, may be this tool can be fix your problem:
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/972034/hu-hu

Comment: No backups unfortunately, I should have made one. I'll erase all my edits even though they're commented, all my changes are at the end of the file. What do you mean by invisible character? Would that show up in Notepad++ or Notepad? I edit all my files with Notepad++

Comment: Some editors made a character, which you can't see.
I sooked this once when I maked a html file and I geted a strange character.
The character on there on my page, but I can't see on the editable source (on notepad++)
In this case, if you have this character, this is a very serius issu.
Try it the program which I linked it, but before make backup you're host file, becouse this overwrite this.